# Defining a sheaf of differential operators

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, d-modules

I have two questions related to the coordinate-free definition of $\mathcal{D}$-modules provided in Ginzburg's [notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecautis/dmodules/ginzburg.pdf) (see pages 24-25):

1. Exercise 2.1.13 says that Diff($M,M$) is almost-commutative, i.e. that the associated graded ring $A$ is commutative. But the zeroth graded piece is simply $A$-linear homomorphisms from $M$ to $M$, in which composition $f\circ g$ need not be commutative in general. What am I missing?
2. We define $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ (for $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ coherent) on $X$ by defining it on the basis of open affines of $X$ by
   $$\Gamma(U,\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}))=\text{Diff}_{\mathcal{O}(U)}(\mathcal{M}(U),\mathcal{N}(U)).$$ How do the details work out? I'm confused, in particular, about how to construct the restriction maps
   $$\rho_{VU}:\text{Diff}_{\mathcal{O}(U)}(\mathcal{M}(U),\mathcal{N}(U))\to \text{Diff}_{\mathcal{O}(V)}(\mathcal{M}(V),\mathcal{N}(V)).$$
   Is the coherence hypothesis on $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ needed/used here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on $\mathcal{D}$-modules, but hopefully I can help a bit.

---

For 1, you're probably right. If $M = N$ is also equal to the base ring $A$, then yes, $\operatorname{Diff}(M,M)$ will be an almost commutative ring, sometimes denoted $\mathcal{D}(X)$ if $X$ is the affine scheme $X = \operatorname{Spec}A$ (of course using the sheaf definition in your question 2 you get a sheaf for any scheme).

Ginzburg himself in "[Differential operators and BV structures in noncommutative geometry](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3392)" points out that there is a subtlety here (see Defs. 2.1.1 and 2.1.2, Rem. 2.1.12): you can do what Ginzburg did in his notes that you linked (which matches EGA IV$_4$ §16.8; see 16.8.1), or you can define $\operatorname{Diff}_0(M,M)$ as the image of $A$ in $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,M)$. In the latter case, you have $\operatorname{Diff}_0(M,M) = A$ and the almost commutativity follows by the same proof as for $\mathcal{D}(X)$.

In the former case, as you pointed out, you don't get almost commutativity. I would say asking around on MathOverflow (Why are their two definitions as listed in Ginzburg? How do researchers distinguish them? When is one better than the other?) or even just e-mailing Ginzburg himself is not a bad idea…

---

For 2, there are a couple of ways to do this. Let me first sketch what one might do after learning sheaves à la Hartshorne, using (quasi-)coherence. For each affine open subset $U \subset X$, let $\mathcal{D}_U(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ be the $\mathcal{O}_U$-module associated to $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal{M}(U),\mathcal{N}(U))$ (see §II.5 in Hartshorne). This gives you the maps $\rho_{VU}$ that you wanted, provided $V$ is contained in some affine open subset.

Now we take what we defined locally to get a sheaf defined on all of $X$, using the "Glueing Sheaves" exercise in Hartshorne (Exc. II.1.22): you can glue together the $\mathcal{D}_{U_\alpha}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ defined on an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ if you have isomorphisms $\varphi_{\alpha\beta} \colon \mathcal{D}_{U_\alpha}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})\rvert_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta} \to \mathcal{D}_{U_\beta}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})\rvert_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}$ satisfying the cocycle condition. So you can try to make sense of what the association above using associated sheaves really means, and then check the cocycle condition.

But who wants to do that. The easier way to see it is by noting $\operatorname{Diff}(M,N)$ is a sub-vector space of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(M,N)$ (by "additive" Ginzburg means $k$-additive, I believe). What follows is an adaptation from [SGAIII, Exp. VII$_\mathrm{A}$](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.polo/SGA3/Exp7A-23mai11.pdf).

Let $p \colon X \to \operatorname{Spec} k =: S$ be the structure morphism for $X/S$. Give $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ the structure of $p^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{S}$-modules via the map $p^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{S} \to \mathcal{O}_X$ obtained by adjunction from the structure morphism (in this case $p^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{S}$ is probably just the constant sheaf $k$). Then, the way you defined $\operatorname{Diff}(M,N)$, we can construct $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ as the subsheaf of $\operatorname{\mathscr{H}\!om}_{p^{-1}\mathcal{O}_S}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ whose sections on an open set $V$ contain morphisms whose restrictions to $U \cap V$ are in $\operatorname{Diff}_{\mathcal{O}(U \cap V)}(\mathcal{M}(U \cap V),\mathcal{N}(U \cap V))$ for each basis open set $U$. The advantage of this over the construction above is that we found a globally defined sheaf that locally agrees with the $\mathcal{D}_{U_\alpha}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$, hence is exactly what we would've gotten from the glueing construction by the uniqueness statement in Hartshorne, Exc. II.1.22.

Comment: This cleared up a lot of things, thanks! One remaining question I have is the following. In proving that $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ is a subsheaf of $\operatorname{\mathscr{H}\!om}_\mathbb{C}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ one needs to show (more or less) that derivations $s_i$ over restrictions $V_i$ glue to a derivation $s$ over $V$ (for $V$ open affine, say). The sheaf condition on $\mathscr{H}$ yields a homomorphism that restricts to the $s_i$, but how does one show that there exists $k$ such that for any $k+1$ functions, repeated ad action on $s$ yields 0?

Comment: The obvious thing to do would be to use the sheaf condition on $\mathcal{N}$ together with the commutativity of some diagram to conclude that ad action by any $\max_{i\in I} k_i$ functions on $s$ yields 0, where the $k_i$ are the orders of the $s_i$. Unfortunately, this $\max_{i\in I} k_i$ is not well-defined -- the open cover might yield sections with orders following an infinite arithmetic progression. Does (quasi-)coherence of $\mathcal{M}$,$\mathcal{N}$ come into play? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Well you want to show that the differential operators $s_i$ on the $V_i$ glue together to get a section of $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ on $V := \bigcup V_i$. Now by definition, the $s_i$ glue together to a section $s$ in $V$ of $\operatorname{\mathscr{H}\!om}_\mathbb{C}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$. Now we want to show $s$ is actually a section of $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ as I defined it. But this is clear: the sections on $V$ are precisely those that live in $\operatorname{Diff}_{\mathcal{O}(V_i)}(\mathcal{M}(V_i),\mathcal{N}(V_i))$ for each $i$…

Comment: and $s\rvert_{V_i} = s_i \in \operatorname{Diff}_{\mathcal{O}(V_i)}(\mathcal{M}(V_i),\mathcal{N}(V_i))$. I think the confusing thing is that we kind of cheat here—we don't use the definition about successive ad's at all when we say what $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ is at all, except to say that locally in each $V_i$ there must be some $k_i$ such that ad-ing $k_i$ times gives you $0$ (this is the condition I put on the sections of $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$). But as you say it's definitely true that globally $\max\{k_i\}$ might be infinite.

Comment: Note that this is really going off of Ginzburg's definition, since his Def. 2.1.15 really only says that you need the ad condition only locally, so there's no reason there should be a finite $n$ such that a global section will give $0$ after ad-ing $n$ times. (This scares me too, though—it doesn't jive well with Def. 1.1.1 in the part of SGAIII I linked to). Again there isn't any (quasi)-coherence involved.
Also, one thing is true: on any affine (or in general, quasi-compact) scheme we *will* have a finite $n$ for each differential operator, since we can choose a finite affine cover.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what with all the open sets flying about, so let me try to be more precise. Let $U$ be open, and $\{U_i\}$ an open cover, with $s_i$ on $U_i$ compatible and ad-nilpotent above $U_i\cap V$, $V$ any basis open. We obtain $s$ on $U$ restricting to $s_i$ from the sheaf-ness of $\mathscr{H}$; it remains to check that $s$ is ad-nilpotent above $U\cap V$, $V$ any basis open. But I don't think this follows immediately from ``sections on [$U\cap V$] are precisely those that live in ... for each $i$,'' as the $U_i$ that we are additionally restricting to are not arbitrary basis opens.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I understand why those two are the same for basis opens... sorry for for being so confused! It seems to me that the first should be much larger, as its sections on U need not be ad-nilpotent (on $U$), which is not true for the latter.